# Need to delay setting css link stylesheet attrib

Tags: jquery, css, timeout, fade

I am trying to delay the link attrib so that it is applied after the content has faded out. But adding a timeout function does not work. Any ideas?

```
$(function () {
    $(".layout a").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { $("link:first").attr("href", $(this).attr('rel')); }, 500)
    $.cookie("Layout", $(this).attr('name'), { expires: 365, path: '/media', secure: true });
    $('.content, .searchresults').fadeOut(500).delay(500).fadeIn(275);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); // Scroll Window back to Top
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being defeated more by the scope of `this` than the timing.

The expression

```
$(this).attr('rel');
```

is fine in itself but inside a `setTimeout` function, `this` no longer refers back to the clicked element.

Good news is that the problem is easily overcome by assigning `$(this).attr('rel')` to a local variable at a suitable point where `this` still refers to the correct object.

In addition, to guarantee the timing, you can move the would-be setTimeout function to make it a callback to the `fadeOut()` expression.

Adding these two things together, the code is as follows :

```
$(function () {
    $(".layout a").click(function () {
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $.cookie("Layout", $(this).attr('name'), { expires: 365, path: '/media', secure: true });
        $('.content, .searchresults').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $("link:first").attr("href", rel);
        }).delay(500).fadeIn(275);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); // Scroll Window back to Top
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your example works after correcting a typo in $(that).attr('rel') to $(this).attr('rel') .. thank-you for your help!

Comment: Whoops, I played with two different approaches in the editor and ended up posting a hybrid. Well worked out. Corrected above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a timeout to correspond to a delay you can assign a callback to the fadeOut function:

```
$(".layout a").click(function () {
    $.cookie("Layout", $(this).attr('name'), { expires: 365, path: '/media', secure: true });
    $('.content, .searchresults').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("link:first").attr("href", $(this).attr('rel'));
    }).fadeIn(275);

    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    return false;
}
```

Look at the jQuery reference for more info: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

I've generally had little to no luck altering a stylesheet loaded through a link tag through javascript though.